# How to upload a youtube video via REST api from url?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload a video to youtube via data api, but cannot figure out where to put the url where the file is located?

Is there any possibility without a library just via https request?

I can find this in the docs:

```json
{
  "snippet": {
    "title": "Summer vacation in California",
    "description": "Had fun surfing in Santa Cruz",
    "tags": ["surfing", "Santa Cruz"],
    "categoryId": "22"
  },
```

but no file or path url here. It says:

Call the script

The list below defines the script's command-line arguments:

file: This argument identifies the location of the video file that you are uploading.

```
Example: --file="/home/path/to/file.mov"
```

But I would like to implement it as mentioned without libraries.

I was also able to figure out the following mentioned in the docs:

This method supports media upload. Uploaded files must conform to these constraints:

```
Maximum file size: 256GB
Accepted Media MIME types: video/*, application/octet-stream
```

Maybe someone has an example request how to do it, like this example to upload a FACEBOOK video:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/[page-id]/videos
```

with the following parameters:

```
file_url = XY,
description = XZ,
access_token = EA
```

Maybe there is an easy solution like this example for youtube as well.

Thanks!

Reading the official docs.

Comment: You have to pass multipart mixed content.